# Python turtle color not filling in properly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm trying to draw Totoro from the ghibli movie but the body won't fill properly.

Here is [the drawing](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/10/ca/a410cabe19bb65412567e53f66ddb82e--studio-ghibli-free-printable.jpg) I'm trying to do, with [this colors](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--ZSJafMiH--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/vhgy3ui1eqmpvouw1ebe.png) , but [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9ySk.png) what I got. This is my code:

```
from turtle import *
"""corps"""
import turtle

def corps():

    speed("fast")
    color('black'),width(2)
    begin_fill()
    up()
    #right side down
    goto(0,-200)
    down()
    right(90)
    forward(4)
    circle(5,90)
    forward(70)
    circle(130,90)
    forward(140)
    circle(50,20)
    up()
    #left side down
    right(-160)
    goto(0,-200)
    down()
    forward(4)
    circle(-5,90)
    forward(70)
    circle(-130,90)
    forward(140)
    circle(-50,20)
    up()
    #right side up
    right(70)
    goto(205,-79)
    down()
    forward(5)
    circle(20,70)
    circle(100,10)
    circle(500,10)
    circle(200,30)
    circle(3800,3)
    right(33)
    forward(30)
    circle(100,23)
    circle(5,115)
    circle(200,15)
    right(63)
    forward(70)
    up()
    #left side up
    goto(-205,-79)
    down()
    forward(5)
    circle(-20,70)
    circle(-100,10)
    circle(-500,10)
    circle(-200,30)
    circle(-3800,3)
    right(-33)
    forward(30)
    circle(-100,23)
    circle(-5,115)
    circle(-200,15)
    right(-63)
    forward(65)
    turtle.fillcolor('#66615D')
    end_fill()
    up()
    #belly
    begin_fill()
    turtle.fillcolor('#A99E82')
    goto(0,-200)
    down()
    circle(200)
    end_fill()

corps()
done()
```

This must be ugly, but I'm just starting to learn how to code.

I don't know if there is an efficient way to draw pictures with turtle use like maths or whatever, but I did it a little randomly.

Answer (score 3):

@RogerAsbey is correct on this point (+1):

> If you could do the outline in one continuous line it would fill
>   evenly.

So let's rework the code to do so.  You can still think about it in discreet parts, but just make sure one flows to the next instead of jumping around:

```
from turtle import *

speed("fastest")
width(2)

color('#36302A', '#545049')

begin_fill()

up()
goto(0, -200)
right(90)
down()

# right side lower
forward(4)
circle(5, 90)
forward(70)
circle(130, 90)
forward(140)
circle(50, 20)
circle(50, -20)
backward(140)
right(90)

# right side upper
forward(5)
circle(20, 70)
circle(100, 10)
circle(500, 10)
circle(200, 30)
circle(3800, 3)
right(33)
forward(30)
circle(100, 23)
circle(5, 115)
circle(200, 15)
right(63)

forward(130)

# left side upper
right(63)
circle(200, 15)
circle(5, 115)
circle(100, 23)
forward(30)
right(33)
circle(3800, 3)
circle(200, 30)
circle(500, 10)
circle(100, 10)
circle(20, 70)
forward(5)

# left side lower
right(90)
backward(140)
circle(50, -20)
circle(50, 20)
forward(140)
circle(130, 90)
forward(70)
circle(5, 90)
forward(4)

goto(0, -200)
right(90)

end_fill()

# belly
fillcolor('#A99881')

begin_fill()
circle(200)
end_fill()

hideturtle()

done()
```

[image]